# Passing values from Java action to next Java action in Oozie workflow

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, oozie, oozie-workflow

I have two java actions written in Oozie workflow.xml. I want to pass output of my first java action to next java action for re-use.

I know this needs to be done using "oozie.action.output.properties". In the first action i am setting the output parameter "buildFileName" as shown below:

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("oozie.action.output.properties"));
LOGGER.info("SystemGetProperty:" + System.getProperty("oozie.action.output.properties").toString());
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("buildFileName", buildFileName);
OutputStream os= new FileOutputStream(file);
props.store(os, "");
os.close();
```

But unfortunately, in the second action, i am not able to use the parameter value. The application job is getting successful, but the parameter value is coming null.

My first java action looks like :

```
<action name="java-action1">
    <java>
        <main-class>XYZ.MyJavaAction</main-class>
        <arg>Args</arg>
        <capture-output />
    </java>
<ok to="java-action2"/> 
<error to="fail"/>
```

My second java action looks like :

```
<action name="java-action2">
    <java>
        <main-class>XYZ.MyJavaAction</main-class>
        <arg>{"outputFileName":"${wf:actionData('java-action1')['buildFileName']}"}</arg>
    </java>
<ok to="End"/> 
<error to="fail"/>
```

Could anyone please help what i am missing here ?

Comment: From the Oozie docs for Java action : _" The capture-output element can be used to propagate values back into Oozie context, which can then be accessed via EL-functions. This needs to be written out as a java properties format file. The filename is obtained via a System property specified by the constant `oozie.action.output.properties`"_

Comment: Read. The. Docs. Even better, read a tutorial such as the old _"Hooked for Hadoop"_ series (2013) - although I can't remember whether it covers that specific point.

Answer (score 3):

A Google search on `oozie capture_output java` points straight to the [Java Cookbook](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OOZIE/Java+Cookbook) section *"Capture-output element"*, quoting:

> - In this example, we pass a the PASS_ME variable between the JAVA action and the PIG action.
> - The PASS_ME variable is given the value 123456 in the JAVA action ...
>     The `main()` method writes a Property file to the path specified in the `oozie.action.output.properties` ENVIRONMENT variable ...

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.setProperty("PASS_ME", "123456");
 File file = new File(System.getProperty("oozie.action.output.properties"));
 OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
 props.store(os, "");
 os.close();
```

> - The PIG action subsequently reads the value of the PASS_ME variable and passes it to the PIG script ...
>     `<param>MY_VAR=${wf:actionData('java1')['PASS_ME']}</param>`

Comment: Can we do the same with python , I am getting NONE when tried accessing property in python using  os.environ.get('oozie.action.output.properties')

Comment: `oozie.action.output.properties` is a Java property, not an environment variable. If you want to use Shiton _(and yes, that term is opinion-based)_ then you likely use a Shell action, and it works differently. Do some research.